# String reverse using recursion exit criteria

Tags: c, recursion

```
void reverseSentence() 
{ 
    char c; 
    scanf("%c", &c); 

    if(c != '\n') 
    { 
        reverseSentence(); 
        printf("%c", c); 
    } 
}
```

What I don't understand here is, if the recursion function is called again and again, when does the control go to print function and print the call stack?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A way to reverse a string using recursion in C strange to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882314/a-way-to-reverse-a-string-using-recursion-in-c-strange-to-me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this code, let's first look at the non-reversing version:

```
void reverseSentence() { 
    char c; 
    scanf("%c", &c); 

    if (c != '\n')
    {
        printf("%c",c); 
        reverseSentence(); 
    }
}
```

It reads *one* character from stdin, and if that character isn't a newline, writes it back out. Then, instead of looping explicitly, it implicitly loops via recursion to read and print the next character:

```
local> echo "The elephants are coming!" | ./a.out
The elephants are coming!local>
```

The function is reading in and printing *one* character on every recursion.  Now if we reverse the order of these two lines as in the original:

```
        reverseSentence(); 
        printf("%c",c);
```

The same thing happens except now we're putting procesing the next character ahead of processing the current one:

```
local> echo "The elephants are coming!" | ./a.out
!gnimoc era stnahpele ehTlocal>
```

Still reading in and writing *one* character on each recursion but taking advantage of the fact that recurring first, then processing the current item processes data in reverse order.  Processing the current item and then recuring, processes data in the forward order.

Answer (score 2):

When the function calls itself the printf just goes on hold, until the called function is done.

With input "Hi\n" it will look like this:

```
scanf -> H
reverseSentence()
    scanf -> i
    reverseSentence()
        scanf -> \n
        return
    printf -> i
    return
printf -> H
return
```

Stepping through with a debugger could help you understand.

Comment: Isn't the if condition defined for both the function call as well as for the printf function.So does that mean when the condition is satisfied it skips both of them?

Comment: Yes. When the condition isn't satisfied (c = \n) it will skip both of them and not print the newline.